# video capture device OpenCV compatible?

Tags: opencv, firewire

what  external video capture device (svideo or rca) with mac os and win xp support can I buy? My software was developed with OpenCV/JavaCV

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, OpenCV just works with USB connection. If I understood your question, you are thinking that is possible to use Svideo or RCA to make the communication, alright?
OpenCV uses the USB connection to capture videos/frames. The Svideo or Rca connection are for TV or capture video hardwares.

Comment: sorry the question maybe will be
which external hardware is compatible with mac and windows?